# Element not found in parent view (ODOO 12)

Tags: python, xml, python-3.6, odoo, odoo-12

i'm working on odoo 12 (python 3.6) and i'm trying to inherit from the product.template and hide the barcode field , but i had this error:

```
element'<xpath expr="//field[@name='barcode']">' not found in parent view
```

this is my gesimmo_views.xml

```
<odoo>
    <record model="ir.ui.view" id="view_form_gesimmo">
      <field name="name">Product</field>
      <field name="model">product.template</field>
        <field name="inherit_id" ref="product.product_template_form_view"/>
      <field name="arch" type="xml">
          <xpath expr="//field[@name='standard_price']" position="after">
              <group>
              <field name="surface"/>
                  <!--<field name="refimmo"/>!-->
              </group>
          </xpath>
          <xpath expr="//field[@name='barcode']" position="attributes">
             <attribute name="invisible">1</attribute>
      </xpath>
      </field>
    </record>
</odoo>
```

**PLEASE HELP !**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have applied the wrong reference. Only just change the reference to this **product.product_template_only_form_view**

Thanks

Comment: it worked with another field(standard_price) but i have a problem with making the label invisible , can you help me please

Comment: @Hello_world you can simply do it with adding the nolabel="1" on that field.

Comment: the problem is solved , i tried this solution and it worked  <xpath expr="//label[@name='default_code']" position="attributes">
            <attribute name="invisible">1</attribute>
        </xpath>  but now i have a problem with a Many2many field that i want to make it invisible … can you help me please ?

Comment: the Field: taxes_id  from product.template

Comment: @Hello_world use this id = 'product_template_form_view' to inherit and then added the XPath to the same field ['taxes_id'] to set invisible

Comment: `raise ValueError('External ID not found in the system: %s' % xmlid)
odoo.tools.convert.ParseError: "External ID not found in the system: GestionIMMO.product_template_form_view"` i had this error

Comment: @Hello_world wrong declaration. used like this product.product_template_form_view